# Monitor Number of VMs on each Eucalyptus Node

Tags: nagios, cloud, eucalyptus

I have setup a small Eucalyptus based cloud for my company.  I would like to use Nagios to track the load on the Node Controller systems to keep track of how many VMs are deployed on each controller.  How can I obtain this information from either the Cluster Controller, or the Node Controllers themselves?  The euca2ools only give aggregate information about the cluster itself, but not about the individual nodes.

Comment: Installing nagios client on each virtual instance, and setting a nagios server on e.g. CC machine is not an option?

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I have never used Eucalyptus

However, it looks like Eucalyptus has some sort of built-in ability to send passive check results to nagios, directly:

http://open.eucalyptus.com/wiki/EucalyptusMonitoring_v2.0

They apparently provide a README about this, as well:
https://geni-orca.renci.org/trac/browser/eucalyptus/eucalyptus-2.0.0/tags/neuca-0.11/extras/README.monitoring?rev=2721

This readme assumes nagios is installed locally, but you could cram NSCA in the middle, to forward results to another nagios instance.

Here is a write-up that someone else put together (see step 4):
http://www.soa.si/2011/07/25/monitoring-eucalyptus-cloud-with-nagios-and-ganglia/

Comment: Thanks for the links. I already have my Nagios server setup to pull the information they talk about.  It will tell me if the Node Controller is up, but won't tell me how many instances are running on each Node Controller.  That is what I'm really looking for.